# How to keep receive input from a user using a loop

Tags: java, netbeans-8

I have 2 projects in netbeans, project1 and project2.

I need to send input data from project1 to project2 to process, but I want project2 to keep looping infinitely and keep receiving the input so that it will keep processing until I stop it manually.

Is this possible?

Comment: run a thread in your second project, that constantly checks for new input

Comment: You are looking for a multi-threaded client server program using [sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20229553/how-to-build-a-multithreading-socket-server)

Comment: can you teach me how to run the thread?

Comment: Improved grammar. Removed "infinite-loop" tag - people searching for that will not be interested in this question.